# Generating Powerpoint file or Converting generated Excel file to power point in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, phppowerpoint

I have Generated an Excel file using PHPExcel and i wanted to convert the file to power point.
Is there any alternative way to generate power point file directly, or how to convert the generated excel file to power point.

Comment: Have you tried PHPOffice https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPPresentation

Comment: Thanks mazedlx for the head up .I  have already generated the excel file i wanted to convert the file to power point slide in PHP Codeigniter.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to convert xlsx to pptx with PHP in any easy way.

Comment: Yeah but i am stack-overflowed to this problem i must do it anyway looking forward.

Comment: @ASahra Are you sure your question makes sense in the first place? What would you expect to see in a slide of the presentation? I would expect some portion of the data, but which one? Take a look at this, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-data-from-Excel-into-PowerPoint-3ec295e9-1bfd-47ff-8d7d-8b838caef853

Comment: @user152807 what I want is conversion of Excel file to power point which insert an image and some data on power point slides .this is my point of favor

Comment: Then follow mazedlx's suggestion, try out PHPPresentation.

Comment: @user152807 the question is to convert the Excel generated file to power point,i have already generated excel file so for the purpose of conversion i can't do it with PHPPresentation.

Comment: I believe your only option is to embed the xlsx file into pptx using PHPPresentation as an object. Alternatively why can't you generate an xlsx and a pptx at the same time with one with PHPPresentation and the other with PHPExcel?